# Firestore delete document and all documents referencing it

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

this question is regarding Firebase (+ Flutter)

is it possible to delete a document and all documents referencing it?

Lets assume i have a structure like this:

```
-users (collection)
  - name
  - bookmarks ((sub)collection)
    - postId
-post (collection)
  - userId
  - name
  - ...
```

Now if i delete a post, i want to delete all bookmarks referencing that post. (From all users). Is there an automatic way (coming from RDBMS).

Another question:
How can i query all posts and "join" the user infos.

Something like this:

```
return firestore
        .collection("posts")
        .orderBy("createdAt")
        .snapshots(); // I want to join the userInformation
```

And are these nested queries then and counting to the api limit?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

you have to query the docs and then batch delete them.  i don't use subcollections, and i'm not going to look up how to query them, but with a root level schema you'd delete the post with a standard firestore delete, referencing the documentID.  assuming the documentID is the same as your 'postID' field (and if it isn't, refactor your schema) you'd then:

```
final WriteBatch _batch = Firestore.instance.batch();

  QuerySnapshot _query = await dbUsers.where('postId', isEqualTo: thatDocumentID).getDocuments();

  _query.documents.forEach((doc) {
    _batch.delete(dbUsers.document(doc.documentID));
  });

  await _batch.commit();
```

be aware that batches can only be done 500 at a time:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

so you'd have to split up your `_batch.commit()` calls as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

There is no automatic method to do what you want.  Firestore isn't a relational database, so relationships between documents are not enforced.  There are no "join" operations in Firestore.

You could instead query for the documents to delete, the delete them all after you iterate the query results.

Comment: So lets assume i have 10.000 users with their bookmarks. I have to go through all of them, check if the id = my post id and remove it?

If thats so, i would elevate the bookmarks to the root level, to make easier queries. But then the question remains, how do i add the necessary information. Do you have a pseudocode example how to add the user information to the post returned?

Comment: I don't have an example.  I suggest you make an attempt on your own and ask another question if you have problems with that.