# Delete Key/Value from anywhere in Firestore

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I'm Using python with `firebase_admin`. Is there a way to eliminate a key/value from anywhere in the firestore database?
e.g. I have referenced a document id in some other documents of other collections. When I cancel the document, I want all the references to that document to be deleted as well.

Of course, I'm looking for a solution without having to read every document looking for the value to delete.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52048204/firestore-delete-document-and-all-documents-referencing-it

Comment: Well it says there is no way without reading or at least querying all the data 

Comment: That is correct. Firestore is a NoSQL solution, which isn't a relational database service. As such querying the documents manually is the advised approach, but keep in mind that indexes are required for every query in Firestore, which ensures good performance. More info here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firestore delete document and all documents referencing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52048204/firestore-delete-document-and-all-documents-referencing-it)

Comment: @siamsot in the question you posted they come to the same conclusion: there is no way to do it without iterating through all the objects because firebase is non relational.

Comment: You mention a key: value pair. If you know the path to the object (the collection name and the documentId), then yes, you can delete it anywhere it appears. For example. Suppose you have a users collection with documents corresponding to each user. If the documentId is the user id, then the path would be /users/user_id and that could be directly removed without a query.